# Limit of sequence of arguments

Tags: complex-analysis

In an example in Brown and Churchill's complex analysis book they take a sequence $z_n=-2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ and show that $z_n \to -2$. However when using polar coordinates letting $r_n=|z_n|$ and $\Theta_n= \text{Arg }z_n$ we get $r_n \to 2$ which is clear and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Theta_{2n}=\pi$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Theta_{2n-1}=-\pi$ without justification.

Can anyone explain how did they find the limits for $\Theta$? Since there isn't any clear way to find the principle argument.

I tried using $\arctan((-1)^n/-2n^2)$ but I still got one limit.

Comment: Can we think about $\arctan(x)$ when $x$ goes to $0 \pm$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Isn't it $n\pi$ for $n\in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I still don't get your comment